# using HSQL as in memeory data store

Tags: hsqldb, in-memory-database

I am planning to use HSQL has a inmemeory datastore(only inmemory /no disk backup) .Then i wil take periodic backup of HSQL every x min (eg 15 min ) so that i can restore the data in case if box goes down for some reason.

Few doubts:

```
1)Is HSQL good for storing large amount of data . (Eg 15 GB)
2)Will search be good ? I guess yes since it is inmemory
3)Any other concerns?
4)Have you used HSQL for such purpose?
5)Any other open source which supports SQL like queries. I know memsql but its not open sourced
```

Comment: @All : why is noone answering

Comment: [possible solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11959008/can-hsqldb-handle-a-few-millions-of-rows)

Answer (score 2):

Yes. I have used HSQL DB as in-memory database. I run a stand-alone java application with 20 GB heap and HSQL DB. I have faced no problems. Application process nearly 1 million records everyday and has round 12GB of data.

I do not see major concerns with HSQL DB. But, concurrent access and locking is something which has to be taken care properly.

There are many open source in-memory databases.

Derby (Java Db), H2, HSQL DB.

You can also use MySQL, PostGRESQL, Oracle Coherence (recently released)

Answer (score 2):

[Here](http://lightjavadatabase.blogspot.ru/) is a nice article which will maybe help you with your decision.

What I think:
I have intensively used HSQLDB 2 years ago in in-memory mode but not with very large amount of data (2-3 GB) and it performed well enough. However it was said that it is not the best solution for production usage.

HSQLDB doesn't support full text search - use H2 for it. Also H2 has built-in support for clustering and replication according to their [comparison](http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#comparison).

If you don't need ACID in your application and feel that key-value storage is enough - I certainly recommend using Redis. It is designed to perform well on in-memory data and certainly can handle milions of rows.